# Bootstrap tooltip is not working with react.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I was trying to use bootstrap tooltip on button to display complete information. But it is not working. Tooltip is not getting displayed.

Here is my react code:

```
<button type="button" ref="data" value={this.props.data} onClick={this.submit} className="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title={ this.props.data }>
{ this.props.data.length > 20 ?
this.props.data.substring(0, 20)+'...' : this.props.data }
</button>
```

I even try to include it using bootstrap's javascript method like:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
</script>
```

What should I do for it?
Thank you..

Comment: is it because of your placement, where it cannot be seen ? .. try changing data-placement ? ..

Comment: Just ran into the same issue, fixed by using react-bootstrap tooltip component (which does a good job even if I'm not satisfied using this huge amount of code for something that simple).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do use bootstrap tooltips with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656024/how-do-use-bootstrap-tooltips-with-react)

Answer (score 8):

I can only guess without a demo that you are calling `.tooltip` on document ready, but before the component has actually rendered.

Try:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.attachTooltip();
},

componentDidUpdate: function() {
  this.attachTooltip();
},

attachTooltip: function() {
  $(this.refs.data).tooltip();
  // Or for React <0.14 -
  // $(this.refs.data.getDOMNode()).tooltip();
}
```

PS consider giving your button ref a more meaningful name than 'data'

Comment: I tried your approach but it's not working. Browser is showing tooltip but without any css like just data in rectangular box with white background and black default font text,  not in a bootstrap way like black background with white text.

Comment: @SwapnilBhikule sounds like the css isn't loaded?

Comment: No. CSS is getting loaded because all other bootstrap css like navbar, divs etc are working correctly inside react.

Comment: Why dont you use react-bootstrap tooltip component??

Comment: I think this is a genuine clash between bootstrap tooltip and react inner workings, I am having the same problem and could not get it to work reliably (I tried exactly what @DominicTobias suggested in this answer before I found this question). I could not switch to react-bootstrap tooltip so I switched to jquery-ui tooltip since I was importing that already for other stuff in my project.

Comment: you can also select by the data-toggle attribute: `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` as described in the Bootstrap documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Comment: @ManishJangir I think because event after 1.5 year - it still in active development, so...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

`data-html="true"`

inside the button tag.

It's a property which shows HTML as text.

Answer (score 0):

1.import Jquery first.

const $ = window.$;

2.Call componentDidMount function.

```
componentDidMount() {
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  
}
componentDidUpdate() {
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

3.Use the following properties

```
 data-toggle="tooltip"
 title="Main PDF"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Swapnil I too had the same problem got the tooltip but without css, then found that have to initialize tooltip so I did like this

```
componentDidMount() {
   window.$(this.refs.test).tooltip();
}
In my textbox, I have reference attribute like ref='test' and initialized tooltip..viola It worked for me.. Hope it helps u..
```

Answer (score 0):

Import jQuery in **componentDidMount()**,

```
componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

and add **window.$** to a const function,

```
const $ = () => window.$;
```

and then you can use tooltip like,

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use bootstrap5's tooltips in one of my react.js project and getting suffer to implement it. Then, I have found a solution that helped me. Let me tell how I solved it.

**For Functional Component**

1. First I have installed the bootstrap into my project by `yarn add bootstrap` and then added popper by `yarn add @popperjs/core`.
2. Then imported `import { Tooltip } from "bootstrap";` in `app.js` file.
3. Then created an `useEffect` and added this code inside it.

```
    var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(
      document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
    );
    tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
      return new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
    });
```

Hope it will help you to get rid of the issue.