# How do use bootstrap tooltips with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I had tooltips working earlier and am trying to migrate my component to React. I'm not using react-bootstrap yet because I'm not sure if I'm going to because it's still under heavy development and not 1.0 yet.

Here's a snippet of what my render code looks like:

```
<span>
    <input data-toggle="tooltip" ref="test" title={this.props.tooltip}  type="radio" name="rGroup" id={"r" + this.props.name} />
    <label className="btn btn-default" htmlFor={"r" + this.props.name}></label>
</span>
```

And calling it:

```
<MyComponent name="apple" tooltip="banana" />
```

I know you have to call the tooltip function to get it to show up and I think that's where I'm messing up. I'm currently trying something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    $(this.refs.test).tooltip();
    // this.refs.test.tooltip(); ?
    // $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); ?
}
```

But none of this seems to be working. The tooltip isn't showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the problem. I was putting the `data-toggle` and `title` on the wrong element (it should go on the label instead). Also, `$(this.refs.test).tooltip();` works fine.

Answer (score 21):

Without using refs / React DOM, you can select tooltips by data-toggle attribute:

```
componentDidMount() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

Source: [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Note, if you're loading jQuery by CDN, you can refer to it by window.$ as well.

Comment: Worked perfectly. This is the exact answer that I was looking for.

Comment: I get `'$' is not defined`

Comment: @RossAttrill, you need to install jquery (npm i jquery --save) and then import it (import $ from 'jquery'; ).

Answer (score 8):

I know it s an old question, but to avoid side effects with bootstrap/jquery/react, if you want tooltips, use this :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip

It's very easy to use and works better than bootstrap tooltip in a react project

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution for tooltip on react app. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better if you use real React components because React only writes to the DOM so it cannot recognize any changes made my others which could clash with.

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap

```
const tooltip = (
  <Tooltip id="tooltip">
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
  </Tooltip>
);
const overlay = (
    <OverlayTrigger placement="left" overlay={tooltip}>
      <Button bsStyle="default">Holy guacamole!</Button>
    </OverlayTrigger>
);
```

(Example taken from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/)

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the real DOM representation, try this please:

#### 12.x

```
$(this.refs.test.getDOMNode()).tooltip();
```

#### 13.x

```
$(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.test)).tooltip();
```

#### 14.x

```
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
$(ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.test)).tooltip();
```

Comment: It appears this is deprecated. I tried the updated version along with some other variants and none of them seemed to work.

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried and the tooltip still isn't showing up. I'm thinking it might have something to do with `data-toggle` or `title` not being recognized in React or something.. I'm not sure. Also DOM should be capitlized in your ReactDom example.

Comment: have you tried the to console.log() the result of Reacts.findDOMNode() ?

Comment: >>Also DOM should be capitlized in your ReactDom example.<<
No, its just a local variable it could be `foo` as well ;)

Comment: Oh yeah right I'm just including it from the cdn and theirs is capitalized. I'll try logging it. Edit: Yeah it's being found and the object is being logged.